# How to access redux store in private route?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to access auth state from my redux store in private route. I can get default state but cannot get updated state from store. I have stored my current user data and token in store. I can access these value from all other components except my private route component.
I have provided some code below

> AdminRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const AdminRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authState = useSelector((state) => state.authState);
  console.log(authState.currentUser);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        authState.currentUser?.id ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/auth" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default AdminRoute;
```

> Store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { uiReducer } from "../slices/uiSlice";
import { authReducer } from "../features/auth/authSlice";
import { userReducer } from "../features/user/userSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    uiState: uiReducer,
    authState: authReducer,
    userState: userReducer,
  },
});
```

authSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiUrl } from "../../api/apiConfig";
import Axios from "axios";
import { tokenConfig } from "../../utils/tokenConfig";

export const userLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/userLogin",
  async (userData, { rejectWithValue, dispatch }) => {
    const { email, password } = userData;
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.post(`${apiUrl}/auth/login`, {
        email,
        password,
      });
      if (data) {
        localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
        return data;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (!err.response) {
        throw err;
      }
      return rejectWithValue(err.response.data?.msg);
    }
  }
);

export const getCurrentUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/getCurrentUser",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue, getState }) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.get(
        `${apiUrl}/user/cUser`,
        tokenConfig(getState)
      );
      if (data) {
        return data;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (!err.response) {
        throw err;
      }
      return rejectWithValue(err.response.data?.msg);
    }
  }
);

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    isLoggedIn: false,
    currentUser: null,
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [userLogin.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading";
    },
    [userLogin.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "success";
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
      state.token = action.payload.token;
    },
    [userLogin.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "failed";
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    [getCurrentUser.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loading";
    },
    [getCurrentUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "success";
      state.currentUser = action.payload;
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
    },
    [getCurrentUser.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "failed";
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
 const { actions: authActions, reducer: authReducer } = authSlice;
 export { authActions, authReducer };
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your protected route should be rerendered when the redux state updates. Perhaps you could remove some of the complexity.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const AdminRoute = (props) => {
  const authState = useSelector((state) => state.authState);
  return authState.currentUser?.id ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/auth" />
  );
};
```

And just ensure you render the `AdminRoute` like any other regular `Route` component.

Ex:

- ```
  <AdminRoute path="/protected" component={PrivateComponent} />
  ```
- ```
  <AdminRoute
    path="/protected"
    render={props => <PrivateComponent {...props} />}
  />
  ```
- ```
  <AdminRoute path="/protected">
    <PrivateComponent />
  </AdminRoute>
  ```

Comment: if i use last approach for my route, i can see updated state in admin route but after that route is no more protected.